# How to print in Angular with template

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular2.
I found this solution: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-printing-solution-example-3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
But i don't understand this completely.

In this example is showed printing with app.component.html.

In my app i have recipe-detail.component.html and inside i have button with function print().
I would like to print content from recipe-detail.component.html and include LogoSite and footer.

How i should do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have mentioned in the question they are using window.print() for printing.

Initially the component app-print-page is made hidden using the css

```
app-print-page {
  /* hide the printing component from @media screen */
  display: none;
}
```

Used the below style for print . app-main-page components display set to display : none since we don't need to print that components view. app-print-page display set to display: block we need to print that component view.

```
@media print {

  app-print-page {
    display: block;
  }

  app-main-page {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

you can re use this same logic in your component .

Comment: Okay. But where i should write it. In this example those pages are in app.component.html. Where i should write mine?

Comment: I dont your application structure. But what you have to do is use the print media query and hide the portion that you don't need print and make visible the components that you need to print.

Comment: If you can provide a stackblitz page i can help you

Answer (score 0):

Sayooj V R is right with his answer in conjunction with the link you provided.

In the stackblitz example the @media print tag is held in the main styles.css in the root directory of the project.